# How to check whether a number there in integer variable?

Tags: java

For example, we can find what we search in an array as below:

```
    int values [] = {3, 5, 7};
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        if(values[i] == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("3 is in array.\n");
        }
    }
```

but what would happen if we search a number in integer value? Can we find what we search in that variable? I tried something with for each loop but it hasn't worked. Does Java provide this process?

```
    int value = 151;

    for(int found: value)
    {
        if(found == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("3 is in array.\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (Integer.toString(value).contains("3"))` ...

Comment: @IMurali : I suggest you take  a course on Java...:  Example : https://www.coursera.org/learn/introjava

Comment: @Tom don't do that. That's extremely ugly code, not a single bit versatile, and inefficient. Go the arithmetic way instead. That's only 5 lines or sth like that and way better code.

Comment: @Paul Now please guess why it is a comment, not an answer ...

Comment: @Tom well, **I** could guess it. Now scroll down and take a look at the answers... . And if that's not enough, OP is obviously new to this stuff, so it's definitely not a smart idea to post this kind of code without any comment. I can say it's bad code. OP most likely won't be capable of realizing this though.

Comment: @Jayan I don't think I need a course for a method :)

Comment: @Paul "Now scroll down and take a look at the answers..."* I'm not responsible for someone else's answer.

Comment: @Tom I didnt say you were. I just wanted to show that it's quite dangerous to post low-quality code since newbies are quite prone to reusing it because they don't realize it's low quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [`String.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
if (Integer.toString(value).contains("3")) { ... }
```

Comment: This luckily doesn't look like a copy of my comment ... ;P.

Comment: Sorry dude I was actually typing + looking for the link x_x

Comment: I don't care much, because my comment wasn't serious, so don't worry ;).

Comment: Haha coolio, why wasn't it tho? I feel like this is very valid

Comment: I meant my comment under this answer. That wasn't serious.

Comment: @ldos please don't post that as an answer. That's extremely ugly code, inefficient, and not exactly versatile.

Comment: @Paul I respectfully disagree. As you can see in the "duplicate" question, Jon Skeet gave (kinda) exactly the same answer. And this specifically answers the OP's question. So you may downvote like you did, but I am going to keep this here

Comment: @Idos well, it's been accepted. The fact that it's not good style to use this kind of code remains. Shouldn't be presented to a newbie IMO, but well apparently there are other opinions on this topic...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not a neat way of doing it, nevertheless it is one of the ways to do it. 
Steps involved:
1) Convert it to String. 
2) Look for a particular character in that string using String's built in contains(CharSequence s) method

```
int value = 151;
//First Step:
String numberAsString = Integer.toString(value);
//Second Step:
if (numberAsString.contains('3')){
System.out.println("Found 3");
}
```

And remember variable value is not lost. You can use/reuse it.

Comment: @Tom oh sorry. My bad. Yes variable value is not lost. Why not just use that instead of unnecessarily changing String back to Integer? I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Glad to see, that you improved your answer :).